# jQuery UI Tabs - Anchor to Internal Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm having trouble using jQuery UI (v1.11+) Tabs with internal anchor links. My code is as follows:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tabs").tabs();

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
                <ul class="tabs-list">
                  <li> <a href="#tabs-1">
                    <div class="tab"> Tab 1 </div>
                    </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#tabs-2">
                    <div class="tab"> Tab 2 </div>
                    </a> </li>
                </ul>

                <div id="tabs-1">
                  <div><a href="#">Text for tab 1</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                 <a href="#"> Text for Tab 2</a>
                </div>
</div>
```

I am having trouble trying to link to these tabs from text links that are at a different area of the page. The objective is to smoothly scroll after clicking each text link to the designated tab:

```
<a href="#tabs-1">Link to Tab 1</a>
<a href="#tabs-2">Link to Tab 2</a>
```

I've tried various searches here, including using the beforeActivate function (since all "select" examples are outdated with newer jQuery UI versions), but nothing works for me. Can someone please assist? The jQuery UI docs do not show examples of this.

Comment: So what's your issue? aren't you able to make this tab working? or you want to add some scrolling in tabs?

Comment: I wasn't able to get text links to activate the tab and scroll smoothly down to the tab. Nisihit figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/dqy1h2or/3/) .

use `active` option of tab to make selected from external resources. check more [HERE](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

use `beforeActivate` event Triggered immediately before a tab is activate . check [HERE](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate)

HTML

```
 <div id="tabs">
            <ul class="tabs-list">
              <li> <a href="#tabs-1">
                <div class="tab"> Tab 1 </div>
                </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#tabs-2">
                <div class="tab"> Tab 2 </div>
                </a> </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">
              <div><a href="#">Text for tab 1</a></div>
              </div>


              <div id="tabs-2">
             <a href="#"> Text for Tab 2</a>
            </div>
 </div>
<a href="#tabs-1" class="external-tab">Link to Tab 1</a>
<a href="#tabs-2" class="external-tab">Link to Tab 2</a>
```

JQUERY

```
var tab ;
$("#tabs").tabs({
  beforeActivate :  function( event, ui ) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#tabs").offset().top }, 1000);
  } 
});

$('.external-tab').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
   tab = $(this).attr('href');
   var index = $('div[id^=tabs-]').index($(tab));
  $('#tabs').tabs( "option", "active", index );
});
```