# How to link navigation menu to jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header navigation menu that I need to link to jQuery tabs - the links therefore have to open a tab on the same page and link to tabs and open them from another page. I got it working from another page, but don't know how to open a specific tab with external link on the same page, without including separate headers for each subpage, that uses tabs linked in the nav.

Here is a Jsfiddle, but there are problems with it, because the link in the navigation lead to external files. The gist is, that the navigation should work both from external pages and then on the same page as well just to open a tab

http://jsfiddle.net/vbonoL5b/

This is part of the menu (its 2 level ul menu)

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul><li><a href="index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>#tabs-1" class="tabLink">Concept</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>#tabs-2" class="tabLink">Benefits</a></li>
                    </ul>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

The tabs are really simple jQuery tabs:

```
<div id="icon-tabs">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="item1" ><div class="icon-tab"><h4>Concept</h4><img src="img/concept.png"></img></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="item2" ><div class="icon-tab"><h4>More</h4><img src="img/benefits.png"></img></div> </a></li>
              </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
           ....
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried some things but I never manage to get the links open on the same page:

```
$(function() {
//Load tabs
 $( "#icon-tabs" ).tabs();

//Check url and open appropriate tab (for when you come from external site)
 if(document.location.hash!='') {
    //get the index from URL hash
    tabSelect = document.location.hash.substr(1,document.location.hash.length);
    $("#icon-tabs").tabs('select',tabSelect-1);
 }  

//Use the nav to open local tabs?? I tried .onclic events based on ID and class of links in menu, but never got it working.
// For example:
 $('.tabLink').click(function(e) {
  if(document.location.hash!='') {
     (e).preventDefault();
     //get the index from URL hash
     tabSelect = document.location.hash.substr(1,document.location.hash.length);
     $("#icon-tabs").tabs('select',tabSelect-1);
   }
  });
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: can you pls provide sample link ?

Comment: Sure, sorry give me minute I have it only localy

Comment: Well I couldnt get it all to work because the #nav menu uses external files in links: http://jsfiddle.net/vbonoL5b/

Comment: fiddle is not working . here what you want to do ?? on nav click page will reload with has and after reload base on # data . related tab will selected ?

Comment: yes,.. something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code  . [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function gives you directly index of element using "ID" attribute

```
$(function() {
//Load tabs
  $( "#icon-tabs" ).tabs();

  //Check url and open appropriate tab (for when you come from external site)
    if(document.location.hash!='') {
   //get the index from URL hash

     tabSelect = $('#icon-tabs div').index($(document.location.hash));
     $("#icon-tabs").tabs('select',tabSelect);       }  

    //Use the nav to open local tabs?? I tried .onclic events based on ID and class of links in menu, but never got it working.
  // For example:
  $('.tabLink').click(function(e) {
   if(document.location.hash!='') {
      e.preventDefault();
     tabSelect = $('#icon-tabs div').index($(document.location.hash));
     $("#icon-tabs").tabs('select',tabSelect);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it seems like the .click function never registers- the url changes, but the code doesn't seem to execute

Comment: what you pass in URL ?  . id of tab?

Comment: this is question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466122/jquery-ui-tabs-anchor-to-internal-links/29466602#29466602

Comment: Sorry I had to go away unexpectadly. Basically what I am trying to do: If you are on another subpage, then the .tabLink links in the navigation should take you to the correct subpage and select the correct tab (this works), but once you are on the correct page, then they should just open the correct tab. - So the links should work both for external and internal linking. I hope I am explaining it correctly. I tried the above and looked at the jsfiddle you posted, but I still cant get it to work- the URL of the page changes, but the tab is not selected/opened.

Comment: Hmm thanks.. Works in the JSFiddle great, but I cant get it to work on my site. I will play around with it and figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: i have added data-tabs="#tabs-1" to your li and remove . from tabLink  class name in li element . so check both html and js changes

Comment: Yes I noticed that. My problem was with jquery version imports. You have been great help, thanks a lot!